# How to get NFT from a list of token accounts in Rust

Tags: metaplex, token, metadata

I have got all token accounts of an owner using

> get_token_accounts_by_owner

method in rust and then parsed it to filter out those with amount = 1. How to confirm if these are NFT or not and if they are NFT then, how to get onchain metadata of these tokens ?

Comment: You can check if they are NFT or Not by looking into the decimals and size of that mint

Comment: ^ Correct and you could also check to see if minting has been disabled

Comment: can we check to which collection the NFT belongs to or check who minted the NFT?

Comment: I still think there isn't a right way to distinguish a non-fungible to fungible token as both can contain metadata. We can't check the collection as most of the old NFT collection have not set the onchain collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFTs and FTs (Fungible tokens) are created with the same [Token program](https://spl.solana.com/token)

The differences between them are:

- token type are created with zero decimal place
- only a single token has been minted.

https://spl.solana.com/token#non-fungible-tokens

Take a look at the example on how to [create an nft](https://spl.solana.com/token#example-create-a-non-fungible-token)

This is how its done in the [metaplex SDK](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/main/packages/js/src/plugins/nftModule/findNftsByOwner.ts#L51)